# Enable Sync to VBlank on LXDE with Intel Video Card

Tags: lubuntu, intel-graphics, lxde, tearing

How can I enable Sync To VBlank in LXDE? My video card is Intel, and I'm having screen tearing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
Option         "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Edit your `/etc/default/grub`

On the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

```
i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.semaphores=1 pcie_aspm=force
```

Comment: I don't have `xorg.conf.d` in `/etc/X11`.

Comment: @sashoalm seems to have been moved to /usr/share/X11 on some debian-based distros such as lubuntu...

Comment: @sashoalm In Ubuntu, there is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` anymore, but creating it is save. Alternatively, you can create it in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. You can check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` if you are unsure, I see the two lines `Option "AccelMethod" "sna"` and `Option "TearFree" "true"` in it.

Comment: Confirmed this works for Lubuntu 15.10 with intel graphics. Just need to add `20-intel.conf` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. No need to change `/etc/default/grub`.

Answer (score 0):

just install the intel hd graphics OR processor microcode firmware for intel cpus from intel-microcode on the preferences>additional drivers after you install it all is done

Comment: You can improve your answer with a screen shot. Also note there are additional things to setup tear-free such as `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and adding line `Option      "TearFree"    "true"`. Welcome to AskUbuntu and thank you for your answer.
`

Comment: Your answer would look great with a screen shot.