# Low FPS on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, video, intel-graphics

Guys, is everything ok? So, I'm using Lubuntu 16.04, it's a good system very fast and security. But I can't see videos with good quality and fast speed (action) or even play light games. I have an Intel Baytrail Processor (N2930), My graphic video card is an Intel `Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)`. It's not the "intel_idle.max_cstate=1" issue. I tried to use the 4.11 Kernel, installed Oibaf Drivers, I have Mesa updated and all, but nothing increased the FPS.

I ran glxgears and that's the results:

vblank_mode=0 glxgears

```
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
1321 frames in 5.0 seconds = 264.145 FPS
1506 frames in 5.0 seconds = 301.098 FPS
1474 frames in 5.0 seconds = 294.780 FPS
1632 frames in 5.0 seconds = 326.380 FPS
1469 frames in 5.0 seconds = 293.576 FPS
1479 frames in 5.0 seconds = 295.740 FPS
1515 frames in 5.0 seconds = 302.824 FPS
1489 frames in 5.0 seconds = 297.684 FPS
```

Fullscreen is worst than window mode

vblank_mode=0 glxgears -fullscreen

```
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
303 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.528 FPS
366 frames in 5.0 seconds = 73.026 FPS
353 frames in 5.0 seconds = 70.412 FPS
367 frames in 5.0 seconds = 73.226 FPS
```

This is my Xorg config

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver     "intel"
   Option     "NoAccel"   "True"
   Option     "DRI"       "False"
EndSection
```

Thank you all, guys. Please, help me, I'm in love with Lubuntu, it's the only issue I found.

Comment: You should set your expectations according to the intrinsic quality or lack thereof of the hardware you have.

Comment: @MichaelBay I use windows 10 to watch videos and it works fine.

Comment: No doubt. Most Bay Trail are just glorified Windows tablets. Crap for Linux.

Comment: @MichaelBay any chance you can help me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your fps are fine, probably you just need to add vsync to fix stuttering/tearing (Lubuntu/Xubuntu are light-weight os, and they come without vsync). Luckily enabling it's quite easy:
[Enable Sync to VBlank on LXDE with Intel Video Card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240923/enable-sync-to-vblank-on-lxde-with-intel-video-card)
(
there's also the answer solution for Lubuntu 15.10, I can confirm it works fine over the new 17.10, =))

If you want to check the problem just open this "Vertical scrolling test", if vsync it's enabled you will just see a fluent solid text without any segmentation (don't mind the "UNSUPPORTED FOR LINUX"):
https://www.testufo.com/framerates-text#pps=480&count=2

Good Luck!

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: thanks, actually I was just trying to help, It's the first time I answer someone, I'll get better :)